# How can I prove the subspace generated by a linear variety is hyperplane ?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am studying on geometric Hahn-Banach. But I could not follow the proof, since some part of the proof is not understandable for me. Can you help me ?

*Problem:*

Let $K$ be a convex set with non-empty interior in a vector space X. Suppose V is a linear variety in X containing no interiro points of K.
Let M be the subspace generated by V. Then V is a hyperplane in M.

How can I prove this ?

Accoring to a book, since V does not contain $\theta \in K$, we must have $V \neq M$, and therefore V is a maximal proper linear variety in M.

Can you explan

- why does $\theta \notin V$ imply $V \neq M$ ?
- why does V is a maximal linear variety in M ?

How can we prove ?

Thank you.